# Getstream.io - Sending one message to many channels

Tags: getstream-io

What is the best pattern for sending one message from one user to many 'messaging' channels? In my case, it could be as many as 300 or more. From reviewing the documentation, it looks like I need to [query the channels](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/query_channels/?language=js&q=query) 30 at a time, then iterate through those channels and send a message to each one. That seems very cumbersome and I was wondering if there was a better way. Would using [Mult-Tenant and Teams](https://getstream.io/chat/docs/multi_tenant_chat/?language=js) be a solution somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the way you explained (query -> send -> repeat) is the solution.

A batch endpoint would be useful but it might be more involved than expected due to unread message maintenance, push notifications, etc.

However, it's not there today and not planned for very soon either.